# pg_query_params() and placeholders

Tags: php, postgresql, osx-mavericks

Thank you for reading this. Would you provide some pointers as to how to understand and solve the two questions below? I am new to PHP and PostgreSQL. OS: OSX 10.9.5, PHP: 5.6.4, PostgreSQL: 9.4.0

1. I would like to know the reason placing a placeholder in pg_query_params() gives the syntax error. How would you solve this? The reason is I want a user to specify a table name when copying additional data to the table.

Here is a snippet:

```
$params = array(strval($_POST['que_str2']));
$myresult = pg_query_params($connection, 'copy $1 from stdin', $params);
echo "<br />\n$params[0]   <br />\n";

Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: copy $1 from stdin ^ in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php

my_table
```

2. Similar to the question above. I would like to solve the error because I want the user to type in a table name and a file path when copying the data from the file.

Here is a snippet:

```
$params = array(strval($_POST['que_str2']), strval($_POST['que_str1']));
$myresult = pg_query_params($connection, 'copy $1 from $2 DELIMITERS \',\' CSV', $params);
echo "<br />\n$params[0]   $params[1]<br />\n";

Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: copy $1 from $2 DELIMITERS ',' CSV ^ in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php on line 20

my_table /Library/WebServer/Documents/data2.csv
```

==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, PostgreSQL does not support parameterized `COPY` statements.  Per the PG 9.4 docs on prepared statements (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-prepare.html), only `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `VALUES` statements can be parameterized.

What you may have to do is construct the `COPY` statement and interpolate the parameters yourself (with appropriate scrubbing and escaping to mitigate injection, etc.) and then submit it with `pg_query` instead.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot in understanding the pg_query_params() function. Thank you!

Comment: And even if you *could* parameterise a `COPY`, you can't parameterise a table name...